# Disable digit substitution

Tags: winforms, localization, internationalization, arabic, right-to-left

How can I disable the digit substitution (for example for Hindi numerals instead of Arabic ones) for my application (native c++) completely?

I want all the numbers displayed with 0123 instead of ٠١٢٣

There is an option in localization options in windows, but I don't want to change that for the user. Only for my app.

Thank you!

Comment: +1 for explicitly asking to change this behaviour only for your app, not for the user or the system.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly confused by you saying native C++ and still having a WinForms tag...

Assuming that it's a native C++ app without any .Net, I'd look at the `SetThreadLocale` function as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374051%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you for the answer, but this does not work in any case. see this posting the gdi functions do not honor the settings. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/06/16/8603298.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it'll work, but try to call `SetLocalInfo` with the LCType parameter set to `LOCALE_IDIGITSUBSTITUTION`. Take a look at the MSDN documentation for `GetLocalInfo` and `SetLocalInfo`.
It does not seem to be possible to change all values programmatically, also I'm not sure if this will only affect the active process. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but this changes it for the user. I only want to do this for one app.

Answer (score 1):

With minor typographical consequences, you can use the U+FF1x characters instead of U+003x.